# Real World Blind Source Separation

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am aware that Scipy has a few ICA algorithms, like FastICA, but it can only be used if the mixed signal observations are perfectly in sync.

My application is recording audio (speech) using microphones into mono audio files. So FastICA would not work.

In my research, a few others algorithms I have came across are: Jade, AMUSE and DUET. However, I'm not sure to what extent Python has support for these algorithms. I would prefer to stay in the Python programming language if possible.

Let me just add, I highly value ease of interface, built-in functionality of the Python library, as well as computational efficiency. With that in mind, can someone with experience in using Scipy or other relevant Python libraries suggest a suitable alternative?

I have Anaconda 4.0, and am running Python 3.5 -- just let me know what I should import.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the code by installing pyemma toolkit available in python.

```
conda config --add conda-forge

conda install pyemma
```

You can refer to this site for more help: http://emma-project.org/latest/generated/MSM_BPTI.html

Comment: Note that you should install now from the conda-forge channel. $ conda install -c conda-forge pyemma

Comment: @AkashParvatikar can you please update the link? It's broken.